# Only copy files from a particular date from s3 storage

Tags: date, file-copy, aws, amazon-s3

I would like to only copy files from S3 that are from today out of a certain bucket with 100s of files. I tried the following: `$ aws s3 ls s3://cve-etherwan/  --recursive --region=us-west-2 | grep 2018-11-06 | awk '{system("aws s3 sync s3://cve-etherwan/$4 . --region=us-west-2") }'` but it doesn't quite work, I also get files from other dates.
How do I do this correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because in the second `aws s3` you use `sync`. Try `cp` instead. Also you can merge the "grep" and "awk" together.

```
$ aws s3 ls s3://cve-etherwan/  --recursive | awk '/^2018-11-06/{system("aws s3 cp s3://cve-etherwan/$4 .") }'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me

- added a time restriction, here I am selecting for 8:00 to 8:30 on 12/12/19
- slightly modified the awk part, removing typo
- instead of calling `system` *n* times from awk, create a text output and pipe that through bash

Yes, be careful with piping into bash :-)

```
aws s3 ls --recursive s3://cve-etherwan/ 
| awk '/^2019-12-12 08:[0-3]/{
     print "aws s3 cp s3://cve-etherwan/"$4" ."}'  
| bash
```

Answer (score 0):

MLu's answer worked for me, but I had to escape the $4 on Amazon Linux 2.

```
aws s3 ls s3://my-files --recursive --region=eu-west-1 |
  awk '/^2021-01/{system("aws s3 cp s3://my-files/" $4 " .")}'
```

with

- `"aws s3 cp s3://my-files/$4 ."` replaced by `"aws s3 cp s3://my-files/" $4 " ."`
- `awk` will concatenate string by default.